# distinct multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I want to select `distinct` combination of `user age` (a column name) and `user name` (another column name) , but when I write `distinct (user_age, user_name)`, there is `syntax error`. If anyone have ideas how to write `distinct` with `multiple columns` it will be great.

BTW, using `MySQL Workbench/MySQL`

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Leave the parenthesis. Just write SELECT distinct user_age, user_name FROM foo where bar;

Comment: works for me, thanks @dev.null, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answered so that it benefit other people as well.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, so (aside from apparently causing an error) use of parentheses here would be pointless and potentially misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave the parenthesis. Just write

```
SELECT distinct user_age, user_name FROM foo where bar;
```

;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve this

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_age, user_name FROM table WHERE some_condition;
```

OR

```
SELECT user_age, user_name FROM table WHERE some_condition GROUP BY user_age, user_name;
```

Hope this helps